# Azure Storage File Share with Folder Label Permission based on Azure AD and Azure AD Domain Service

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-files, azure-ad-domain-services

I am desperately looking for a solution. Posting this question after wasting almost 4 days. We have a file storage application and we are using Azure File Share to manage the files. The file shared can be connect as a Drive in PC or VM using SMB 3.0 protocol. We are good in this stage. The problem is starting just after it.

Support we have a file shared named **Our Projects**. Inside of this file share lets have 3 project folders.

> Project 1
>
> Project 2
>
> Project 3

We are using AD for user authentication. So, when a user attach a file share into own PC, expecting a solutions like that

> **User One** have the access on **Project 1** folder only
>
> **User Two** have the access on **Project 2** and **Project 3** folders

After lot's of googling getting suggestions to do it using Azure AD Domain Service and VM. I have watched some tutorials on Azure File Share on Pluralist as well. But, I am not getting confident to active our expected solutions.

> Looking for expert suggestions or what could be the best approach to achieve it?
>
> Or is it really possible in azure, what I am expecting?
>
> I really really looking for a good solutions from azure experts desperately.

I am new user in Azure Active Directory and Active Directory Domain Service. Please receive lot's of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please read here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-overview#ad-ds

You can either give users access through either Azure ad ds, or on-prem ad ds by making sure you have a hybrid environment with Azure ad connect so that your users are properly synced across.

After that, you create the Azure file share, then you can mount it and set directory level permissions in that share like you normally would with an on prem server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-overview#configure-directory-or-file-level-permissions-for-azure-files